# What is this sequence? 1, 11, 21, 22211, 33221

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

In this sequence:

> 1, 11, 21, 22211, 33221, 433332211, 44444444332221, ?

Can you guess the next number? What is this sequence?

Hint 1:

> Every number always ends with `1` or `11`

Hint 2:

> If the number ends with `11`, Then the next number ends with `1111` but this is longer, So ends with `1`

Comment: aw it reminds me of http://oeis.org/A005150

Comment: @BenjaminWang this is not look and say sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next number is:

> 5555554444433333211

Here is the process to transform a number to find the next one in the sequence :

> Consider each value ($1$'s,$2$'s,$3$'s,...) separately. Per construction, they will always be written in decreasing order. Then:
>  * First each value $k$ is repeated $k+1$ times: $1$ becomes $11$, $2$ becomes $222$, $3$ becomes $3333$, etc.
>  * Then if a value $k$ is appearing $k+2$ times or more, each block of $k+2$ occurences is replaced by one occurence of $k+1$

Hence:

$1$ becomes

> $11$ and nothing is replaced

$11$ becomes

> $1111$ and the first three $1$'s are replaced by one $2$, making $21$

$21$ becomes

> $22211$ and nothing is replaced.

$22211$ becomes

> $2222222221111$ ; Then the first eight $2$'s are replaced by $33$, the first three $1$'s are replaced by one $2$, making $33221$

$33221$ becomes

> first $3333333322222211$ ; and then $433332211$ after replacements of five $3$'s by one $4$ and four $2$'s by one $3$.

$433332211$ becomes

> first $444443333333333333333221111$ ; and then $44444444332221$ after replacements

$44444444332221$ becomes

> first $44444444444444444444444444444444444444443333333322222222211$ ; and then $5555554444433333211$ after replacements.

Research process on paper:

> [my paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CgXF.jpg)

Comment: How do you found the solution?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena : with pen and peper ;) . From the allure of the sequence I tried to understand when a higher value could appear, and then it was just try and guesses. Having so many $4$'s but no $5$ in the last number helped me understand that this was a two-steps process.

Comment: how many time do you found?

Comment: If you are asking "how much time ?", I think it was between 10 and 15 minutes. I was lucky to be on the right track from the beginning.

Comment: ok, How much paper do you use?

Comment: a 10 per 5 centimeters piece of paper (edited in the answer...) !